# fix this rating issue adding rating on wrong post

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]
[image]
i am having trouble finding the issue,the post with skull shown has 6 reviews given by buyer and 5 stars rating , how ever other post owned by this authur is receiving the same rating and starss ? , the stars and rating should show up only on the post it was given to.

here is small code that gets this stars up.
this is the line of code that shows stars in those boxes

```
if(!function_exists('PricerrTheme_my_account_reviews_area_function'))
{
function PricerrTheme_my_account_reviews_area_function()
{
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $uid = $current_user->ID;

    //------------------------------------- 



        global $wpdb,$wp_rewrite,$wp_query;
        $third_page = $wp_query->query_vars['third_page'];

        $third_page = $_GET['pg'];
        if(empty($_GET['pg'])) $third_page = 'home';    

        ?>  

        <div id="content" class="directly-frame account-cnt">




        <!-- page content here -->  
        <div class="box_title3"><?php _e("My Ratings",'PricerrTheme'); ?></div>         



<div class="my_box3"><div class="shopping_menu_dv">
            <?php

            $using_perm = PricerrTheme_using_permalinks();

            if($using_perm) $rev_pg_lnk = get_permalink(get_option('PricerrTheme_my_account_reviews_page_id')). "/?";
            else $rev_pg_lnk = get_bloginfo('siteurl'). "/?page_id=". get_option('PricerrTheme_my_account_reviews_page_id'). "&";   


            ?>
            <ul id="shopping_menu">
                <li><a <?php  echo ($third_page == "home" ? 'class="actiove"' : ""); ?> href="<?php echo $rev_pg_lnk; ?>"><?php _e("Ratings to Award","PricerrTheme"); ?></a></li>
                <li><a <?php  echo ($third_page == "waiting" ? 'class="actiove"' : ""); ?> href="<?php echo $rev_pg_lnk; ?>pg=waiting"><?php _e("Pending Ratings","PricerrTheme"); ?></a></li>
                <li><a <?php  echo ($third_page == "my_rev" ? 'class="actiove"' : ""); ?> href="<?php echo $rev_pg_lnk; ?>pg=my_rev"><?php _e("My Ratings","PricerrTheme"); ?></a></li>

            </ul>

</div></div>





            <?php

                if($third_page == "home"):

            ?>

                <div class="my_box3">   
                <div class="padd10">    
                <script>

                     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                    jQuery('.dd-submit-rating').click(function() {

                    var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');  
                    var uprating = jQuery("#rating_me-" + id + " :selected").val();
                    var reason = jQuery("#reason-" + id).val();
                    if(reason.length < 10) { alert("<?php _e('Please input a longer description for your rating','PricerrTheme'); ?>"); return false; }

                    jQuery.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/",
                           data: "rate_me=1&ids="+id+"&uprating="+uprating+"&reason="+reason,
                           success: function(msg){

                            jQuery("#post-" + id).hide('slow');

                           }
                         });

                    return false;
                    });

                    //-------------------------



                 });


                </script>
                <?php

                    global $wpdb;
                    $query = "select distinct *, ratings.id ratid from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings ratings, ".$wpdb->prefix."job_orders orders where 
                     ratings.awarded='0' AND orders.id=ratings.orderid AND orders.uid='$uid'";
                    $r = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                    if(count($r) > 0)
                    {


                        foreach($r as $row)
                        {
                            $post = $row->pid;
                            $post = get_post($post);
                            $user = get_userdata($row->touser);

                            ?>

                            <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>">
                                <div class="padd10_only">
                                <div class="image_holder3">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="65" height="50" 
                                src="<?php echo PricerrTheme_get_first_post_image($row->pid,65,50); ?>" /></a>
                                </div>

                            <div  class="title_holder3" >
                            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($row->pid); ?>"><?php echo PricerrTheme_wrap_the_title($post->post_title,$row->pid); ?></a></h2>

                            <div class="c111">Rate:</div>
                            <div class="c111"><textarea id="reason-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>" rows="2" cols="35"></textarea></div>

                            <div class="c111"> <select name="rating_me" id="rating_me-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>">

                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="c111 ck999">
                            <a href="#" rel="<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>" class="dd-submit-rating"><?php _e('Submit Rating Now','PricerrTheme') ?></a>

                            </div>


                            </div> 



                            </div>
                            </div>


                            <?php

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _e("There are no reviews to be awarded.","PricerrTheme");   
                    }
                ?>


           </div></div>    

           <?php elseif($third_page == "waiting"): ?>
                <div class="my_box3">   
                <div class="padd10">       

                <?php

                    global $wpdb;
                    $query = "select distinct * from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings ratings, ".$wpdb->prefix."job_orders orders, 
                    ".$wpdb->prefix."posts posts where posts.ID=orders.pid AND 
                     ratings.awarded='0' AND orders.id=ratings.orderid AND posts.post_author='$uid'";
                    $r = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                    if(count($r) > 0)
                    {


                        foreach($r as $row)
                        {
                            $post = $row->pid;
                            $post = get_post($post);
                            $user = get_userdata($row->uid);

                            ?>

                            <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>">
                                <div class="padd10_only">
                                <div class="image_holder3">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="65" height="50" 
                                src="<?php echo PricerrTheme_get_first_post_image($row->pid,65,50); ?>" /></a>
                                </div>

                            <div  class="title_holder3" >
                            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($row->pid); ?>"><?php echo PricerrTheme_wrap_the_title($post->post_title,$row->pid); ?></a></h2> 
                            <?php echo sprintf(__('Waiting from: %s','PricerrTheme'), $user->user_login ); ?>




                            </div> 



                            </div>
                            </div>


                            <?php

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _e("You have no pending reviews.","PricerrTheme");  
                    }
                ?>


                </div>

  </div>
                <?php elseif($third_page == "my_rev"): ?>

                <div class="my_box3">   
                <div class="padd10">       

                <?php

                    global $wpdb;
                    $query = "select distinct *, ratings.id ratid from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings ratings, ".$wpdb->prefix."job_orders orders, 
                    ".$wpdb->prefix."posts posts where posts.ID=orders.pid AND 
                     ratings.awarded='1' AND orders.id=ratings.orderid AND posts.post_author='$uid'";
                    $r = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                    if(count($r) > 0)
                    {


                        foreach($r as $row)
                        {
                            $post = $row->pid;
                            $post = get_post($post);
                            $user = get_userdata($row->touser);

                            ?>

                            <div class="post" id="post-<?php echo $row->ratid; ?>">
                                <div class="padd10_only">
                                <div class="image_holder3">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="65" height="50" 
                                src="<?php echo PricerrTheme_get_first_post_image($row->pid,65,50); ?>" /></a>
                                </div>

                            <div  class="title_holder3" >
                            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($row->pid); ?>"><?php echo PricerrTheme_wrap_the_title($post->post_title, $row->pid); ?></a></h2>

                            <div class="c111"><b><?php _e("Rated","PricerrTheme"); ?>: </b></div>

                            <div class="c111"><?php

                            echo PricerrTheme_show_stars_our_of_number($row->grade);

                            ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear10" style="float:left"></div>
                            <div class="c111"><b><?php _e("Description","PricerrTheme"); ?>: </b></div>

                            <div class="c111"><?php echo stripslashes($row->reason); ?>
                            </div>


                            </div> 



                            </div>
                            </div>


                            <?php

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _e("You have no reviews.","PricerrTheme");  
                    }
                ?>


                </div></div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- page content here -->  
        </div>  





    <?php

    PricerrTheme_get_users_links();

} }
```

Comment: Is the above provided code is for single post ? as you wrote this lines        $nr_ratings = $r[0]->cnt;
  $sum        = $r[0]->smm; these specify [0] it is not looping

Comment: Yes single post each of them , what can i do to fix this can you kindly assist if its not so much boss thanks.

Comment: FYI, you can use `AVG(grade)` in the SQL, instead of calculating it in PHP.

Comment: You need to pass `$post_id` to the function, and use that in the query instead of `$post_author`.

Comment: $post_id = get_the_ID();           echo pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($post_id);

Comment: the post id makes all stars white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the query using both author and post Id (Or just postId): Because the post's are independent to their ID's and they are unique but post author is just related to post but not independent because author(uid) can have multiple posts but post will have single & unique post ID

I am assuming the post Id is also in the same table for now. And giving you example with both postId, author(uid)

example

```
echo pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($post->post_author, $post_id);
```

Same way modify the function and mysql query

**Function** :

```
function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $post_id)  { ..... }
```

And **Query**

```
$s = "select count(grade) cnt, sum(grade) smm from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings where uid='$uid' and awarded='1' and pid='$post_id'";
```

**Final Code**

```
function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $post_id) {
$concat = '';
$nr_ratings = 0;

 global $wpdb;
 $s = "select count(grade) cnt, sum(grade) smm from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings where uid='$uid' and awarded='1' and pid='$post_id'";
$r = $wpdb->get_results($s);



 if(count($r) > 0)
   {
    $nr_ratings = $r[0]->cnt;
    $sum        = $r[0]->smm;

    if($nr_ratings > 0)
     {

        if($sum > 0)
        $sdd = ceil($sum/$nr_ratings);
        else $sdd = 1;

        for($i=1;$i<=$sdd;$i++)
        {
            $concat .= ' <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/star_full.png" width="15" />';
        }

        for($i=$sdd+1;$i<=5;$i++)
        {
            $concat .= ' <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/star_empty.png" width="15" />';  
          }
       }
       else
        {
        $concat = '';

         for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
           {
            $concat .= ' <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/star_empty.png" width="15" />';
          }
      }
  }
   else
     {
       $concat = '';

         for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
        {
        $concat .= ' <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/star_empty.png" width="15" />';
    }

  }

  return $concat." (".$nr_ratings.")";
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $postid)  { ..... }  i get white page  ,  currently i have this  function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid)  its the end lines maybe ?    i tried adding only   
 pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $postid)  stil white page

Comment: Try the same which which I am giving now   pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($post->post_author, $post_id);  and  function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $postid) { .. }   and mysql query same as my answer

Comment: Before that first tell me what is the postId column name of that postId in table

Comment: i added this line function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid,$postid)  no white page and added other code as instructed all white stars.

Comment: Yes it is due to mysql function returning no rows so need to specify column names properly

Comment: please check this image snapshot of phpmyadmin   https://s18.postimg.org/cd24j5whl/2016_09_14_235109.jpg

Comment: I am unable to visit this link above. Please check

Comment: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2nu3kzp.jpg     or     http://pasteboard.co/39PeuWWzD.jpg   if u cant  check first post i updated with the image

Comment: Yes that is the one ! write the query like this "select count(grade) cnt, sum(grade) smm from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings where uid='$uid' and awarded='1' and PID='$post_id'";

Comment: No sorry this is not the one : search for  " job_ratings" table

Comment: ok sir , its ok no need to say that sir, erm i tested that line it did not work hold on let me get the table snapshot

Comment: Yes seen that, But this is not the one because it is not having grade, uid columns just check for  "job_ratings" table

Comment: wait let me get more code for that job rating i might find it

Comment: check post one updated and coded the php search for string job_ratings to find it , it has some database codes there that can help u

Comment: Yes this helps. We need the coloumn names from "job_ratings" table so check in phpmyadmin like before and update the screen shot of job_ratings table

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/function    download this,  a grey buton wil appear enter capcha and download the file and search for the string it has alot of database colum names for rating     ok  lemme check phpmyadmin

Comment: i think i found it job_ratings it wait

Comment: Got it !! It is pid.  Replace these three lines echo pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($post->post_author, $post_id);
function pricerrtheme_show_rating_star_user($uid, $postid)  { ..... }
$s = "select count(grade) cnt, sum(grade) smm from ".$wpdb->prefix."job_ratings where uid='$uid' and awarded='1' and pid='$post_id'";

Comment: Just I updated my answer use those lines it will be clear

Comment: also check 1st post boss updated image in first post

Comment: Yes that is the one ! I got it through your file also which you have shared so just use the lines in my above updated answer

Comment: can you check post one ,  2nd image , gives white screen ,when i add this line check image ?

Comment: I edited my answer and gave the entire function code just use that one.

Comment: If any issues Just download and use this file I have modified this with those changes  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBr-MC9kZseU1VTS0JnYzR0ZW8

Comment: Thanks buddy !! I love coding stuff so I spent time with you almost whole night now It is morning 5 am for me. And now I am happy that your problem solved now I am going to sleep buddy and even I can sleep happily. Good night :) Cheers  . Don't forgot to voteup and mark my answer :) All the best

Comment: is it possible i can add you on skype hanna21460 , please inbox me saying your from stackoverflow , so i can track and find you as there are so many people trying to flirt with me hehe, please i need you and i will also compensate you for your time cheers.

Comment: Thanks buddy !!  wait let me send you request then

Answer (score 1):

**KrishCdbry** is  one the bestest php GURU i have even incountered i never ever seen so much talented and well experienced coders like **KrishCdbry** the best part was he was so patients and calm and very loving and welcoming and out of all very very helpfull , this gentlel men deserves A++++++++++++ rating for his work master pieace.

Comment: please ad my on skype hanna21460 please

Comment: i will get on skype tomorrow as my skype installation is broke and it gives wite page , so i wil need to install again i thk please send me request and il accept you , wil love to se you on other end thanks once again champ

Comment: Just sent request to you (hanna dean) right ? From UK